# Interactive Brokers API DataTable overwrites rows

Tags: c#, datatable, interactive-brokers

I am using the Interactive Brokers C# API and trying to create a Datatable from the `AccountSummary` object but the rows in the table are overwritten and only show the last value.

I can't figure out what's going on. I thought it might be that the property types match the column names so its over-writing on top on the same row.

**Expected output**

[image]

```
public static DataTable ConverToDataTable(object obj)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    obj.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(f =>
    {
        try
        {
            f.GetValue(obj, null);
            dt.Columns.Add(f.Name, f.PropertyType);
            dt.Rows[0][f.Name] = f.GetValue(obj, null);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    });
    return dt;
}
```

This is the method that calls the ConvertToDataTable() method.

```
public void UpdateUI(IBMessage message)
    {
        switch (message.Type)
        {
            case MessageType.AccountSummary:                    
                ConverToDataTable((AccountSummaryMessage)message);
                break;
            case MessageType.AccountSummaryEnd:
                HandleAccountSummaryEnd();
                break;
            case MessageType.AccountValue:
                HandleAccountValue((AccountValueMessage)message);
                break;
            case MessageType.PortfolioValue:
                HandlePortfolioValue((UpdatePortfolioMessage)message);
                break;
            case MessageType.AccountDownloadEnd:
                break;
            case MessageType.Position:
                HandlePosition((PositionMessage)message);
                break;
            case MessageType.PositionEnd:
                break;
        }
    }
```

This is the object I'm trying to build the datatable from.

```
public class AccountSummaryMessage : IBMessage
{
    private int requestId;
    private string account;
    private string tag;
    private string value;
    private string currency;

    public int RequestId
    {
        get { return requestId; }
        set { requestId = value; }
    }

    public string Account
    {
        get { return account; }
        set { account = value; }
    }

    public string Tag
    {
        get { return tag; }
        set { tag = value; }
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }

    public string Currency
    {
        get { return currency; }
        set { currency = value; }
    }

    public AccountSummaryMessage(int requestId, string account, string tag, string value, string currency)
    {
        Type = MessageType.AccountSummary;
        RequestId = requestId;
        Account = account;
        Tag = tag;
        Value = value;
        Currency = currency;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `ConverToDataTable` from? Are you looping over a list or calling the function on multiple instances of the `AccountSummaryMessage` object in any way?

Comment: Hi Kevin/jstreet thanks for taking the time to answer. Ive added the method that calls the ConvertToDatable() Method.

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding where you would be appending multiple rows. Every time you call `ConvertToDataTable` you are creating a new DataTable with one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the first edit by Kevin and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

You should first loop through and add the columns to the table before adding the row. If you are just trying to create a table with a single row in your `ConverToDataTable` function you need to change it to something similar to this:

```
public static DataTable ConverToDataTable(object obj)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    var dataType = obj.GetType();

    dataType.GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(f =>
    {
        try
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(f.Name, f.PropertyType);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    });

    DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
    foreach (var prop in dataType.GetProperties())
    {
        newRow[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(obj);
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(newRow);

    return dt;
}
```

Edit: To add multiple rows you have several options (as I explained in the comments below. Here are two possible methods:

**Using private table variable within your class to keep appending rows when needed**:

```
private DataDate table = null;

public void ConverToDataTable(object obj)
{
    var dataType = obj.GetType();

    if (table == null)
    {
        table = new DataTable();

        dataType.GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(f =>
        {
                table.Columns.Add(f.Name, f.PropertyType);
        });
    }

    DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
    foreach (var prop in dataType.GetProperties())
    {
        newRow[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(obj);
    }
    table.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

**Using an enumerable type to add all of your rows at once**:

```
public static DataTable ConverToDataTable(IEnumerable<object> obj)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    var dataType = obj.First().GetType();

    dataType.GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(f =>
    {
        try
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(f.Name, f.PropertyType);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    });

    foreach (var item in obj)
    {
        DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
        foreach (var prop in dataType.GetProperties())
        {
            newRow[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item);
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

It might be helpful to read up on enumerable types. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) is a good place to start.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for helping out. I've added a picture of what I am trying to achieve. I am trying show multiple rows. I can get the expected output when I use a datagridview but I cant get it correct when trying to use a datatable instead.

Comment: Are you assigning the return value from `ConverToDataTable` within your function? Or passing an Enumerable type for the `obj` paramter? I don't see any other way to add multiple rows using that function.

Comment: No, neither of those things. I havent ever used Enumerable types before.

Comment: I think you have two choices: 1. you can keep your DataTable as a private/public variable and change the function to either append the returned datatable or change the function to non-static void and modify your DataTable variable. 2. You can pass an enumerable to your function and append all of your rows at once. I will update my answer to show you.

Comment: Thank you so much Kevin, this worked, also read up on IEnumerables, was interesting to see how a for each works behind the scenes.